# I can see forwarded port on canyouseeme website, but not on NMAP scan?

Tags: ip, router, localhost, port-forwarding, nmap

I have forwarded port 14444 using my routers configuration panel.

Here is the screen-cap:

[image]

Then I ran ncat using:

> sudo ncat -k -l 192.168.15.42 14444

https://www.canyouseeme.org/ says "Success: I can see your service on 139.190.16.59 on port (14444)"

Here is the screen-cap:

[image]

But when I run NMAP against the public IP(the same IP as above) it says:

**Not shown: 14444 closed ports**

**PORT   STATE SERVICE**

**53/tcp open  domain**

And to make matters even more complicated, running NMAP against my Local IP says port 14444 is open:

**Not shown: 14444 closed ports**

**PORT      STATE SERVICE**

**14444/tcp open  unknown**

Here is the screen-cap:

[image]

I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

All fine. Canyouseeme shows port open on public address.
But when you run nmap, you in local network, so it shows port open on local ip.
If you run nmap from some remote server, it will show open only on public ip.

Comment: But then why can I see port 53/tcp running NMAP from within my local network against my public IP, but not the one that I am forwarding?